# GNU version of locate - gupdatedb fails with "gfind: failed to read file names from file system"

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina

I try to test GNU version of `locate` command. First, I have to create the database like this :

```
sudo gupdatedb --prunepaths=/Volumes --output=$HOME/locatedb_gupdatedb
```

Unfortunately, 1 minute after launching the command, I still get the following error :

```
gfind: failed to read file names from file system at or below '/': No such file or directory
```

I don't understand where this error could come from ?

**UPDATE 1:** I replaced `gfind` by `find` commad and correct path of `find` which is `/usr/bin/`. Unfortunately, I get embarassing error messages like this when I launch the `gupdatedb` command like this :

```
sudo gupdatedb --prunepaths='/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb /Volumes /System' --output=$HOME/locatedb_gupdatedb
```

Here the error messages :

```
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PKInstallSandboxManager: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.cleverfiles: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/mnt: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.DocumentRevisions-V100: No such file or directory
etc ...
```

I tried to modify into `/usr/local/Cellar/findutils/4.7.0/libexec/bin/gupdatedb` file, the option :

```
: ${FINDOPTIONS="2 > /dev/null"}
```

But the issue is this option is set in front of the command `find`, not at the end, so it is not correct in the following of the file.

Given the fact there a lot of `find` commands after in the script, I can't add manually each time the `2 > /dev/null` terminal option.

Anyone could see how to suppress all these error messages from `find` command when I launch a `gupdatedb` command ?

**UPDATE 2:** I finally managed to create a database with gupdatedb (GNU version of MacOS `updatedb` command) by doing :

```
sudo gupdatedb --prunepaths='/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb /System /Volumes' --output=$HOME/locatedb_gupdatedb
```

The issue now is, when I do a research on a substring of a file or directory, the informations seems to be duplicated in results (`sub_string`  is simply the part of a file or directory name) :

For example, if I do a : `glocate -d ~/locatedb_gupdatedb sub_string`

Then, I have **duplicates results** like :

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/fab/sub_string.dat
/Users/fab/sub_string.dat
```

I don't know how to exclude '`/System/Volumes/Data/`' from these results : however, I have well specified in `--prunepaths` option the directory `System`, why isn't it taken into account in database created by `gupdatedb` ?

Or maybe I should perform a :

```
sudo gupdatedb --prunepaths='/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb /System/Volumes/Data /Volumes' --output=$HOME/locatedb_gupdatedb
```

??

Any help is welcome to exclude this directory

```
/System/Volumes/Data
```

from indexing database.

**UPDATE 3:** Here is an example of **quickly generating a database** with `updatedb on Debian 10 Buster`. **Few modifications of normal using** have been done between the timestamps of the 2 commands `updatedb`.

[image]

So I conclude there is a really a difference betweeen GNU/MacOS and GNU/Linux implementation.

Any explanation is welcome.

Comment: Not sure we are the right place to ask about Linux , it also makes your question rather broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are running GNU's `updatedb` with the macOS's `find`. `gupdatedb` is a shell script that expects to be running a GNU-compatible `find`. In particular, it converts `--prunepaths` to a GNU-compatible basic regular expression.

```bsh
--prunepaths='/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb /Volumes /System'
```

converts to

```bsh
PRUNEREGEX="\(^/private/tmp$\)\|\(^/private/var/folders$\)\|\(^/private/var/tmp$\)\|\(^*/Backups.backupdb$\)\|\(^/System$\)\|\(^/Volumes$\)"
```

GNU BRE [(basic regular expressions)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Regexp-Backslash) treat `\|` as an "alternative" operator:

> ‘foo\|bar’ matches either ‘foo’ or ‘bar’

This is a GNU extension to the BRE syntax, and the macOS `find` operator does not accept it. So the whole prune string fails to match anything.

The macOS (and POSIX) BRE does not have an alternative operator, so it is not a super easy fix. The macOS updatedb script converts the alternative into explicit `-or` operators in the `find` command. You can modify the GNU script to do that. Or get `gfind` to work.

By the way, GNU's updatedb script builds a completely new database from scratch on every run, just like macOS's.

Your Debian installation is using [mlocate](https://salsa.debian.org/tfheen/mlocate) which is a completely different implementation than GNU locate, not as widely ported, and not available on macOS AFAIK. And even though `mlocate` runs quickly on your Debian installation, that does not mean it runs a lot faster than GNU locate. Both run in under a second building the entire database from scratch on my Debian installation when all the disk metadata is in RAM (which is usually the case).

Apple provides `mdfind`, which uses the incremental database created by `mds`, which is largely triggered by file system events. This makes it (theoretically) much more efficient than even `mlocate`, which still has to traverse the entire directory structure looking for changed directories. The problem is that incremental builds accumulate errors. That is why `locate`, with its full rebuild every time, is still around and preferred by many.

Comment: "By the way, GNU's updatedb script builds a completely new database from scratch on every run, just like macOS's. "  : **This is not the case with Linux, isn't it ?**

Comment: @youpilat13 I am looking at the code from [GNU findutils 4.7.0](http://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/findutils/findutils-4.7.0.tar.xz). It is not specific to macOS, so I expect it is the same on Linux. If you look at the code in general, `updatedb` just runs a `find` command to find all the files and then processes the output into a database file. Since `find` has to scan the entire directory tree to find new files anyway, there is no performance benefit for an incremental update (at least not one worth the effort).

Comment: @OlfPro It"s weird, on my Debian, I have not this behavior, updatedb updates only just what has been modified between a last of utilization, typically a few hours or minutes. I conclude the implementation is not exactly the same.

Comment: Do you know a tool that doesn't any to buidd at each time all the hard disk ? `mdfind` is pretty good but instable (sometimes results appear and sometimes not).

Comment: @youpilat13 Let me know what version of updatedb you are running on your Debian system. When I run `apt install locate` on Debian Buster I get the one from GNU findutils 4.6.0 which creates a new `$LOCATE_DB.n` and if successful, replaces the old database with the new one.

AFAIK, `mds` does incremental updates for `mdfind`. If `mdfind` is missing something not excluded on purpose (by privacy settings or turning of indexing of a drive, for example), I recommend using `locate` :-) It does not try to do incremental updates so is much more reliable, if somewhat out of date.

Comment: @OdPro I put an example into **UPDATE3** of just updating on Debian 10 with updatedb. I did few modifications (creating some files, directories between the 2 dates). And as you can see, the database is generated very quickly. So  there is really a difference in implementation between Linux and MacOS.

Comment: @youpilat13 It is not a difference between GNU/macOS and GNU/Linux. Your Debian installation is using [mlocate](https://salsa.debian.org/tfheen/mlocate) which is a completely different implementation than GNU locate, and not as widely ported, and not available on macOS AFAIK. Also, both GNU locate and mlocate take less than 1 second to update the database on my Debian system. You need to compare the two utilities on the same system to get a fair assessment.

Comment: It seems that the answer here is that there actually **is no answer** - or at least not one that doesn't require a large effort to overcome - have I got that correct? I installed my copy of `locate` from MacPorts - I'm a bit disappointed as MacPorts usually just does not release a port that doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple version is run via `/usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` which is a shell script. Some additional paths are excluded from the search there. In Mojave these are

```
: ${PRUNEPATHS:="/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb"} # unwanted directories
```

PS: I don't have Catalina so you may need to check whether other paths need to be excluded as well.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but the issue is about the root directory "/", the message is : `gfind: failed to read file names from file system at or below '/'` .I tried to do, with your sugeestion : `sudo gupdatedb --prunepaths='/private/tmp /private/var/folders /private/var/tmp */Backups.backupdb /Volumes' --output=$HOME/locatedb_gupdatedb`and I get the error message above. Do you  think it's a sudo problem ?

Comment: @youpilat13 It's probably more complex than it seems, the shell script runs `find` and then feeds the result into the locatedb updater. Don't know how the GNU version works but maybe you can just use a copy of the shell script to feed the GNU version.

Comment: Why do you need to use GNU locate when there's already one installed?

Comment: @MarcWilson . Because I expect the GNU version to have the same behavior than on Linux systems, i.e when we have already a database, if we launch another updatedb command after few hours of using, the current database is updated and not erased to build entirely another again. This is a waste of time to rebuild all the database and unfortunately, this is the dafaut behavior of classical updatedb command of MacOS.

Comment: Documentation showing that this is the behavior of BSD locate?