# After upgrade to Catalina getting error "gfind: failed to read file names from file system" when running glocate

Tags: command-line, catalina, unix, filesystem, search

I have installed GNU findutils via Homebrew and I use `glocate` to create a locate database.

The following command worked perfectly under macOS High Sierra:

```
sudo gupdatedb  --localpaths=/ --prunepaths=/Volumes --output=~/locatedb
```

However after upgrading to Catalina (and upgrading all Homebrew formulas including findutils), I get with the same command the following error:

```
gfind: failed to read file names from file system at or below '/': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to fix this? I suspect it has to do the tighter security under Catalina.

---

(Also, I have read [macos - GNU version of locate - gupdatedb fails with "gfind: failed to read file names from file system" - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/397015/gnu-version-of-locate-gupdatedb-fails-with-gfind-failed-to-read-file-names-f) and I am making sure that the gfind command is used not th `find` command, but I still get the error message.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is caused by `(g)find` traversing the `/System` directory. Exclude this directory and the indexing completes without an error:

```
sudo gupdatedb  --localpaths=/ --prunepaths="/Volumes /System" --output=~/locatedb
```

Comment: Very useful! But watch out, the tilde in `--output=~/locatedb` won't expand because it's not at the beginning of the word. Try `--output=${HOME}/locatedb`